# Why ButtonBase doesn't check its Visibility before testing `ICommand.CanExecute`?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, weak-references

I've faced with an issue, that blows up my mind.
 Let's look at these methods from `ButtonBase`:

```
    private void HookCommand(ICommand command)
    { 
        CanExecuteChangedEventManager.AddHandler(command, OnCanExecuteChanged);
        UpdateCanExecute();
    }

    private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        UpdateCanExecute(); 
    }

    private void UpdateCanExecute()
    {
        if (Command != null)
        { 
            CanExecute = MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CanExecuteCommandSource(this);
        } 
        else 
        {
            CanExecute = true; 
        }
    }
```

`HookCommand` is called, when you're assigning new command to the button. It subscribes to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` via weak event manager and updates button state (enabled/disabled).

`OnCanExecuteChanged` is just an event handler, and `UpdateCanExecute` ultimately calls your `ICommand.CanExecute`, when you use something different from `RoutedCommand`. This is the case, when you're working with any MVVM framework.

Now, the problem.
One of my data templates is applied to the `ContentControl` to show some data:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateState}"/>
```

This template is contained within rather complex visual tree inside another `ContentControl`, which is hosted in `ElementHost` (this is a WPF component in WinForms MDI-application). 
There are a couple of buttons inside this template, whose `Command` properties are bound to `RelayCommand`s.

When I close MDI child, which contains visuals, rendered using this data template, buttons try to update their state and call `OnCanExecuteChanged`. This is a big problem, because `CanExecute` calls some disposable object, that already had been disposed.

I know, that:
1) the window (WinForms form) is closed at this moment, because `CanExecute` is called after the `Form.Closed` event is handled;
2) there's no memory leaks - if I mock `CanExecute`, memory profiler shows, that my view model, which contains commands, is collected by GC and no longer exists.

The question.
What's the purpose to check `CanExecute`, if the button isn't visible?
Is there any option to prevent this behavior?

P.S.
The only workaround I see is to keep somewhere in my view models a flag,, which will show, that disposable was disposed, and return `false` from `CanExecute`.
Any better ideas?

Comment: What's the point of wondering why some Microsoft developers developed things the way they did... they just did it that way for whatever reason. How about just using the old `if (disposableObject != null)` before you try using `disposableObject`?

Comment: @Sheridan: may be there's a reason for such a behavior, and I'm doing something wrong. `disposableObject` isn't null, it's just disposed, and checking some flag is my proposed workaround.

Comment: "It subscribes to CommandManager.RequerySuggested" that's the problem i guess, since all your commands are hooked to this event they will all be reevaluated when InvalidateRequerySuggested() it's called, which is happening when you close your window.

Comment: @Dtex: that's right. But I can't think out a reason to check something, that affects visual state, when the button is invisible.

Comment: My suggestion is basically the same as your workaround, have your view models return false if they are disposed.

Comment: @Dennis: Why should your `UpdateCanExecute()` method set `CanExecute` to `true`, if the `Command` is `null`? Seriously, I don't get this line.

Comment: While the behavior may be weird, I'd definitely track and check a bool indicating if my class were disposed.  In fact, my disposable snippet comes with a bool Disposed and AssertNotDisposed() methods...

Comment: @DHN: it isn't mine. It's WPF source code. Because button must be enabled, when there's no bound command. Otherwise you couldn't handle click event

Answer (score 0):

I would give four potential answers, and one guess towards why it is implemented the way it is:

1. Set the `DataContext` of the window which is getting torn down to `null` before you dispose everything.  The button would have no reference on the object, so the exception never gets thrown.
2. Wrap the call to the disposable object in a try/catch which filters `ObjectDisposedException` and returns false.
3. Add a `IsDisposed` property to the disposable object, and check beforehand.  It does seem like there could be a race condition here if you are doing anything on a non-UI or finalizer thread.
4. Hold a `WeakReference` to the disposable object if you are waiting for the finalizer to call `Dispose`, or set the reference to `null` after you call `Dispose()` and check if it is `null` prior to calling upon it.

As far as why command gets queried even when non-visible, consider that the result of the command may control the visibility.  Imagine the following:

```
<!-- This would probably have to be done in some more complicated way, like
     passing IsEnabled to a converter with CanExecute as the parameter, or
     by just binding to IsEnabled. -->
<Button Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=CanExecute}"
        Command="{Binding TheCommand" Content="Do it" />
```

If it did not query the state of the button is hidden, it would never be shown once disabled.